# Angulary and Django REST

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

How can I filtred my queryset?

Simply example:

```
.controller('TViewController', ["$scope", "$stateParams", "Ad", "Banner", function($scope, $stateParams, Ad, Banner) {
    $scope.ad = Ad.get({ ad_id: $stateParams.ad_id });
    $scope.banners = Banner.query();
}])
```

And

```
class CBanner(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img")
    ad = models.ForeignKey(CAds, null=True, blank=True)
class CADs(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
```

They both have viewset, serializer and routing register

```
class AdsViewer(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CADs.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AdsSerializer
etc...
```

How can I filtered this: `$scope.banners = Banner.query();` to get only banners with `ad(foreignKey) = ad_id`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a query parameter to your url, such as:

```
http://example.com/api/ads/?ad_fk=5
```

In `AdsViewer`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """
    This view should return a list of all the ads filtered with proper foreign key
    """
    ad_fk = self.request.query_params.get('ad_fk', None)
    return CADs.objects.filter(ad=ad_fk)
```

For more info see the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)